# Concatenate two files and redirect output with Clojure using terminal

Tags: clojure, filesystems, command-line-interface

I'm trying to reach out to the terminal in Clojure to concatenate two **binary** files together.

So I'm trying to do something like: `cat file1 file2 > target`

I've started looking at [conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) but I can't seem to get `cat` to treat my inputs as file paths rather than strings, e.g.

```
(def files '["/tmp/file1" "/tmp/file2"])

(defn add-to-target [files target]
  (cat {:in files :out (java.io.File. target)}))

(add-to-target files "/tmp/target")
```

The result written to the `/tmp/target` file is:

```
/tmp/file1
/tmp/file2
```

I'm happy to try other (perhaps more Clojure idiomatic) ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just skimmed the documentation for `conch` and your problem seems to be that `:in` is taking the file names as strings not as the files themselves. Why not just use a java `InputStream` to read the files and `OutputStream` to write the target?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The thing is I don't need to really shell out for this. I just needed to understand IO in Clojure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(ns user
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn catto [f1 f2 out]
  (with-open [o (io/output-stream out)]
    (io/copy (io/file f1) o)
    (io/copy (io/file f2) o)))

;; in REPL
;; > (catto "station.mov" "super.pdf" "zzz.bin")
```

Take a look at clojure.java.io docs.

Comment: That works with one adjustment: `io/writer` needs to be `io/output-stream` for binary data. Perhaps you can edit? Thanks!

Comment: See this example to concatenate any number of files: https://gist.github.com/ciaranarcher/8406880